# Seder night songs

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry

In the מגיד section of the הגדה does anybody know if there are any songs/tunes for:

1. יכול מראש חודש
2. מעשה של ברבי אליעזר
3. Any part of the section starting צא ולמד
4. רבי יוסי הגלילי up to דינו

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!